# Python OpenCV: Cannot resize image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I am using Python 3 and OpenCV 3. I am trying to use the EigenFace Recognizer which uses the same size images for the training and test dataset. I read the image from a webcam and I resize the images to 200 x 200 but it shows an error .

This is my code:

```
faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0);
rec=cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
#rec=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
rec.read("recognizer/EigenData.xml")
id=0

fontFace = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale = 1
fontColor = (0, 0, 255)

while(True):
    ret,img=cam.read();

    resize_img = img.resize((200,200) , img)
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(resize_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w, y+h), (0,255,0) , 2)
        id, conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])   #EigenFace Predict
        cv2.putText(img,str(id),(x,y+h), fontFace, fontScale, fontColor,thickness=2)

    cv2.imshow("Face", img);
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break;

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error I get is:

```
resize_img = img.resize((200,200) , img)
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenCV uses NumPy arrays as the fundamental datatype to represent images.  Indeed NumPy has a `resize` method to "resize" the data, but you're not using it properly.  By [consulting the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html), the `numpy.resize` method requires you to reverse the order of your parameters.  The input array goes first followed by the desired size.  You have it almost correct - just swap the order of the arguments.

However, I don't believe this is what you're looking for since `numpy.resize` fills in the output array with repeated copies of the input - especially since you're doing this for facial recognition.  I believe you want to resize the **contents** of the image to fit the desired size, not fill in the array with repeated copies of the input with its original size intact.

Therefore, [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) is a better fit for you.  You call it the same way as `numpy.resize`:

```
resize_image = cv2.resize(img, (200,200))
```

Take note that the default method of resizing uses bilinear interpolation.  If you want to use another method, you will have to provide an additional argument `interpolation` to do that.  If you wanted to perform cubic interpolation, you would do:

```
resize_image = cv2.resize(img, (200,200), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Check the documentation on `cv2.resize` for more details: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Comment: Links to opencv 3.0 beta are bad. I suggest to use links to opencv 3.3 docs

Comment: @Miki I can't find the Python invocations to the functions in the latest docs. Managed to only find it in the 3.0.0 dev.

Comment: You're right. I don't get why new doc doesn't have python functions... However, 3.0 beta (both code and doc) should be avoided. It contains too many bugs / wrong explanations. I'm not the downvoter, btw ;)

Comment: @Miki :D no problem. Should I link to 2.4 then?... But the OP is explicitly using 3...I could link to the official 3.3 tutorial on resizing too.